# How can I fix my Virtual PC 2007 network configuration

Tags: networking, microsoft-virtual-pc, nat

I have installed Windows Virtual PC 2007 on my Windows 2003 R2 Server.
I have installed a virtual Windows XP.
I have configured the virtual PC to use Shared Networking (NAT)
I have disabled the firewall on the virtual windows XP

The problem:
I am unable to PING from Windows 2003 (the host) to the Windows XP (virtual)
I do have normal traffic from the virtual to the internet

Could this problem be related to routing?
How I can I fix this network configuration to allow for the following traffic:
1. From Virtual to Internet
2. From Host to Virtual
3. If possible, from Internet to Virtual on pre-defined ports (port forwarding?)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Virtual PC 2007 help:

> A virtual machine configured to use Shared Networking acts like a computer behind a Network Address Translation (NAT) router. Shared networking does not support inbound port mapping. External computers are unable to access a server running in the virtual machine or any ports on the virtual machine. Shared networking also **does not support networking between virtual machines or from the host operating system to the virtual machine**.

I would try to create two network adapters for virtual machine. The first one is **NAT** for internet access and the second is **loopback** adapter with static IP. You will need to create Microsoft loopback adapter on your host machine and connect it with virtual's second adapter. Both loopback adapters must have IPs from the same subnet.

I didn't try to do it but hope it helps

Comment: well... if it isn't supported I guess I'll need to try something else. Thanks.